# Configure Netbeans to use Symfony - OSX

Tags: macos, symfony, netbeans, mamp

Symfony does not offer an installer package to be downloaded anymore, so I can't point an installer when Netbeans asks me to.

I am working with OSX Sierra. Also coudln't run mysql directly, so I installed MAMP.

That's what I need: run Symfony from Netbeans, using PHP and Mysql from MAMP.

I could run the installer throuh the terminal, but that creates a folder which works with the buil-in PHP server, and when I move it to my MAMP main folder and try to create a new project (in Netbeans) from exisiting resources, it seems to work but then  I have no commands available to run.

Comment: Have you tried to doawnload the symfony.phar ? as described here ? https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find any reference to a symphony.phar file in that page :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal in your OSX Sierra machine.

As you can see in the doc you need to execute those 3 commands to get the Symfony installer (it is a symphony.phar file)

```
 sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
 sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
 sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

After having executed those 3 commands you will get a Symfony.phar file in your global environnement. It's written in the doc:

> In Linux and macOS, a global symfony command is created.

So Now you can go to the www (or htdocs) directory of Mamp (or xampp or wamp) to create a new Symfony project by executing that command:

```
symfony new my_project_name
```

Everything is dscribed here in the doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

If the Symfony.phar file would not have been put in the global environnement by the console command then you would have had to put the Symfony.phar in your www (or htdocs) directory and create a new Symfony project with that command

```
php symfony.phar new my_project_name
```

I Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! I had already tried out something similar, but the issue was with netbeans. Anyway, your answer helped me! But I just figured it out, so I will explain what I did :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I will explain what I did.

I run symfony as Mintho433 explained, so I got a fresh installation in my MAMP server folder.

I received an error about time.zone not defined, I checked it out in my phpinfo() and it was OK, so I dismissed the warning. Bad choice!

I created a new project in Netbeans from existing respources, picking the new folder. But when tryining to select a command in NEtbeans, the list was empty.

I found out that even when you are working with your MAMP server, symfony looks for the built-in PHP server configuration. So I created a new php.ini file in /etc just defining the timezone. Went back to Netbeans, and then the commands were there.